# How to syncronize Vue mounted function with external dependencies?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a Vue mounted function that requires both internal value `foo` and external value `bar`.

myVue.js snippet --

```
//myVue.js
export var myVue = new Vue({
    el: '#my-vue',
    data: {
        foo: null,
    },
    ...
    methods: {
        asyncThatRequiresBothFooAndBar() {
        }
    },
    mounted: async function () {
        this.asyncThatRequiresBothFooAndBar();
    },
    beforeMount: function () {
        this.foo = this.$el.attributes['foo-value'].value;
    }
});
```

and myMain.js main entry point snippnet --

```
//myMain.js
import { myVue } from './myVue';

(async () => {
    await asyncBar();
})();
```

This doesn't work as when Vue triggers mounted, asyncBar hasn't completed.

I also tried the below --

```
//myMain.js
(async () => {
    await asyncBar();
    myVue.methods.asyncThatRequiresBothFooAndBar();
})();
```

but it gives me `Cannot read property 'asyncThatRequiresBothFooAndBar' of undefined` error.

So the question is: How can I manage the synchronization of Vue hooks with both internal and external dependencies?

Comment: Don't instantiate Vue until you resolve dependencies. Put `let { myVue } = await import('./myVue')` after `await` or move `new Vue` to main.js.

Comment: It seems `let { myVue } = await import('./myVue');` is indeed valid syntax, but my webpack chokes on it... any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What exactly does happen when it chokes? Do you use Vue CLI or raw Webpack? At this point this is specific to your setup. I'd expect it to work with default Vue CLI config.

Comment: After hours of googling, I finally get webpack to work with dynamic import (via babel-core: ^7.0.0-bridge.0 I believe...), but now the dynamic import is creating bundle_0.js -- down the endless rabbit hole

Comment: Are you worried about multiple chunks? This is not necessarily a bad thing but it should be configurable, https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/ . Another way is to lazily instantiate `new Vue`, i.e. `export var initMyVue = () => new Vue(...)` and `let myVue = initMyVue()` after `await`.

Comment: Brilliant! `export initMyVue = () => { return new Vue(...); }` and `let myVue = initMyVue();` work beautifully without the annoying bundle_0.js -- I wish I could accept your comment as the best answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application initialization can be postponed by wrapping it with a function:

```
export const initMyVue = () => new Vue(...);
```

An instance can be created when dependencies are available:

```
(async () => {
    await asyncBar();
    const myVue = initMyVue();
    myVue.methods.asyncThatRequiresBothFooAndBar();
})();
```